# Working with GitLab through DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, gitlab

I'm using **GitLab Community Edition 8.6.6 6d3805b**, installed on the machine `gitlab.somedomain.com`. But users can access to this machine only through DNS server `git-remote.somedomain.com`.

All repositories in GitLab have such URLs:

- ssh: `git@gitlab.somedomain.com:username/projectname.git`
- https: `http://gitlab.somedomain.com:9336/username/projectname.git`

(I use port 9336 because there are many others web-services installed on this machine) 
And users can't clone, push or pull in repositories through DNS because it has different hostname.

I tried to change hostname for git as following:

1. Changed the `external_url` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` from
   `gitlab.somedomain.com:9336` to `git-remote.somedomain.com`.
2. Removed data of the previous hostname using `rm -rf
   /opt/gitlab/embedded/nodes`.
3. Reconfigured GitLab service using `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

But GitLab web-ui gave me the following error:

> The service temporary unavailable.

However gitlab-ctl status is ok:

```
:~# gitlab-ctl status     
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 12940) 1464228s; run: log: (pid 442) 1503945s
run: logrotate: (pid 12560) 2557s; run: log: (pid 444) 1503945s
run: nginx: (pid 13061) 2402s; run: log: (pid 445) 1503945s
run: postgresql: (pid 12970) 1464226s; run: log: (pid 440) 1503945s
run: redis: (pid 12972) 1464225s; run: log: (pid 438) 1503945s
run: sidekiq: (pid 13052) 2402s; run: log: (pid 441) 1503945s
run: unicorn: (pid 13131) 2379s; run: log: (pid 439) 1503945s
```

How can I adjust GitLab to make it running correctly through DNS?

P.S. I can't change the hostname of `gitlab.somedomain.com` because there are many services installed on it. I also can't rename DNS server because I haven't enough rights.

Comment: By `exteral_ip` do you mean `external_url`?

Comment: Yes. Post fixed.

Comment: Is it actually `exteral` or `external` - check your typos